# What is cppcheck rule-file <pattern> syntax?

Tags: regex, customization, pcre, cppcheck

I've poked around for a while, and can't find this anywhere.  I have found a nice example of a cppcheck rule-file that shows a simple pattern;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rule version="1">
  <pattern>if \( p \) { free \( p \) ; }</pattern>
  <message>
    <id>redundantCondition</id>
    <severity>style</severity>
    <summary>Redundant condition. It is valid to free a NULL pointer.</summary>
  </message>
</rule>
```

Which works nicely, as long as all the pointers are named 'p' and the call is 'free'.  How do I change 'p' to match any identifier? How do I check for "'free' or 'delete'"?  Is the pattern a grep/awk/sed pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

Cppcheck uses [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/). So use a regular expression that follows the Perl rules.

I'm not really good at Perl regular expressions so I can't answer how/if you can match any identifier (since it should be matched twice).

.. hope that helps a little at least.

Comment: follow on question.  I have a single line file; `foo = (char*)logMsg.c_str()`  and used '--rule=".+"' to find out that parsed to 'foo = logMsg . c_str ( )'.  What happened to the '(char *)' cast?  How would I test for that cast in a rule-file?

Comment: There is 'unsimplified' code available internally where casts are kept but this internal 'unsimplified' code can't be accessed from a rule. I guess we could add an attribute or something in the rule file that requests that the 'unsimplified' code is used. Feel free to open a ticket in the Cppcheck trac if you need this.

Comment: @DanielMarjamäki any comments to the [suggestion I just posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24059161/2932052) - is it right from your POV?

Answer (score 0):

From my regex experience, I'd try this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rule version="1">
  <pattern>if \( (\w+) \) { free \( \1 \) ; }</pattern>
  <message>
    <id>redundantCondition</id>
    <severity>style</severity>
    <summary>Redundant condition. It is valid to free a NULL pointer.</summary>
  </message>
</rule>
```

Where these PCRE features replace the `p` of your original example:

- `(\w)` is a word pattern (of alphanumeric chars and `'_'`), caught in group #1
- `\1` is the back-reference to the text which matched the pattern

---

An **elaborated description** can be found at Martin Moene's Blog: [Find code patterns with CppCheck](http://martin-moene.blogspot.de/2014/04/search-with-cppcheck.html)

Answer (score 0):

change the p into dot(.) so that it means any character